# How to determine countability of $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N \times \Bbb N$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Is $\Bbb N \times\Bbb N \times\Bbb N$ countable or not, where $\Bbb N$ is the infinite set of all natural numbers ?

Please explain how it is done.

Comment: It's a good exercise in the definitions to show the following far more general proposition: Any finite product of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Failing that, it is likely that your course/text/whatever would have already established that $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ is countable.  This can be used to show that your set is countable.

Comment: Yes, we did cover N X N but I didnt understand it. Is it possible for you to show me how this is countable ?

Comment: Maybe trying to reproduce the argument for NxN being countable will lead to some enlightenment.

Comment: @GdgamesGamers The usual proof is a diagonalization argument.  You put all pairs (1,x) on the first row, (2,x) on the second, (n,x) on the n-th row, with $x$ coinciding with the column.  You then go diagonals with finitely many elements in them.  Every pair lies on such a diagonal, and there is one such diagonal for every row (the diagonal containing $(n,1)$).  You can now express $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ as a countable union of finite sets, which is countable.  Alternatively, you can give a fairly explicit enumeration from this diagonalization.

Answer (score 10):

Define $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ by $f(m,n,l)=2^m3^n5^l$ and observe that $f$ is injective by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Notice how this can be extended to show that any finite number of copies of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable.

Comment: What a marvelous proof! +1

Comment: A related function was used by one of my professors to prove that $\Bbb Q$ is countable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ is countable, here's a sketch for $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ being countable.

We know there is a bijection $f\colon\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$.  Use this to construct a bijection $g\colon \Bbb N\times\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Let $(x,y,z) \in \mathbf{N}\times\mathbf{N}\times\mathbf{N}$, let $w=x+y+z.$ What do you know about each $w \geq 3$ in relation to $x,y,z$?

Comment: This is not an injection. $(1, 2, 3)$ and $(1, 3, 2)$ both map to $6$, for example.